# Using Selenium with IE10 to automate pages developed in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I’m currently working on a project to use selenium to Automate pages developed in Angular JS.
The test run fine in Firefox 25 on a windows box, But when I run the Same Tests through IE 10, I get random failures. The tests click incorrect elements on pages causing the tests to timeout and fail.

I’m using selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2 & IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0 drivers.
I’m also using CSS selectors not x-paths as I read somewhere x-paths might be the issue.

Comment: It's best to identify element by Id. If you encounter scenarios where the wrong element is clicked, I suspect you might be using a CSS selector that is not unique to the element you wish to select.

Comment: Hi cruellays, as some of the pages are autogenerated not all the elemenets have id's heres an example of a css selector im using its unique [heading='%s'], im using a data provider to feed in the header name.

Comment: The problem is really specific - there is no generic and correct answer. Please provide the details: code, web-site link or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Did you try to increase implicit waiting time of the ie driver?

Comment: Here is the code i'm using:                                   String mySelector = String.format(CSS_SELECTOR, name);
getWaitdriver().until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(mySelector)));
element = getWebDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(mySelector));
System.out.println("CLICKED CSS SELECTOR  " + mySelector);
element.click();

Answer (score 0):

Set IE NativeEvents to false. That can be one of the reasons. Set something like this:

```
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions{EnableNativeEvents = false};
Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks a million Saifur {EnableNativeEvents = false} worked!! :)